# Permanently store sqoop --map-column-hive mapping for DB2

Tags: hive, db2, sqoop, oozie

I am importing several DB2 database tables with an Oozie workflow that uses Sqoop to import to Hive. Currently I have to map each column with an unsupported data type manually with "--map-column-hive".

Is there any way to permanently store mappings for specific data types? I am importing several tables that contain DB2-"Character" columns which all have to be mapped to HIVE-"STRING" manually.
For ~50 tables there are ~200 columns that use the datatype "Character" for FKs which have to be mapped manually.

I want to permanently save that DB2-"Character" is mapped to the datatype HIVE-"STRING".
Can this be done?

regards

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, Sqoop does not provide ability to pass type-to-type mappings as parameters.
They are all [hardcoded explicitly](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/a50394977bcdec8ae2274618b3a5c9e7e6a1082b/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/hive/HiveTypes.java#L55-L90):

```java
switch (sqlType) {
  case Types.INTEGER:
  case Types.SMALLINT:
      return HIVE_TYPE_INT;
  case Types.VARCHAR:
  case Types.CHAR:
  case Types.LONGVARCHAR:
  case Types.NVARCHAR:
  case Types.NCHAR:
  case Types.LONGNVARCHAR:
  case Types.DATE:
  case Types.TIME:
  case Types.TIMESTAMP:
  case Types.CLOB:
      return HIVE_TYPE_STRING;
  case Types.NUMERIC:
  case Types.DECIMAL:
  case Types.FLOAT:
  case Types.DOUBLE:
  case Types.REAL:
      return HIVE_TYPE_DOUBLE;
  case Types.BIT:
  case Types.BOOLEAN:
      return HIVE_TYPE_BOOLEAN;
  case Types.TINYINT:
      return HIVE_TYPE_TINYINT;
  case Types.BIGINT:
      return HIVE_TYPE_BIGINT;
  default:
  // TODO(aaron): Support BINARY, VARBINARY, LONGVARBINARY, DISTINCT,
  // BLOB, ARRAY, STRUCT, REF, JAVA_OBJECT.
      return null;
}
```

Also there's a specific case for [XML columns in DB2](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/f4f9543010e6bacc8db938ab81c239c2273691ea/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/manager/Db2Manager.java#L286-L303):

```java
if (colTypeName.toUpperCase().startsWith("XML")) {
  return XML_TO_JAVA_DATA_TYPE;
}
```

If your column type is not recognized by this mapping + user-defined mappings via
`--map-column-hive` parameter, you'll get an exception.

What I'd do in your case (if not considering manual column mapping):

1. Make sure once again that type mapping for DB2-"Character" does not work
2. Download the sources of your Sqoop version, add a new if-branch in `Db2Manager.toDbSpecificHiveType`, build and test with some your tables
3. Create a PR and wait for the next release OR use the customized version of Sqoop (might be painful when you want to upgrade Sqoop version)

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer.
I also noticed that the mapping of the types is done in the source code of Sqoop.
_My problem is not that manual mappings using "--map-column-hive" do not work_, since they do flawlessly. My problem is to _manually map ~200 columns_ with "Character" data type to the Hive data type "String" which is _very cumbersome_.
I am currently not willing to build Sqoop with changed source code because, as you said, updates would not work correctly anymore.
If nobody has another suggestion, I would accept your answer (even if it doesn't really solve my problem).

Comment: Yet another option — create a wrapper script to [collect metadata from DB2 side](https://dataedo.com/kb/query/db2/list-columns-names-in-specific-table) for all CHARACTER columns and form a single string to pass as map-column-hive value